# Magento2 override module-ui base admin template file?

Tags: magento2, admin, requirejs-config.js, ui, overriding

i want to override following file in my custom module so that when magento admin sales grid renders this template from vendor it would take file from my module:

```
vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\web\templates\grid\listing.html
```

Can anyone let me know how to achieve this?I have tried with requirejs-config.js mapping but its not working anymore

Comment: Yes correct understood

Comment: Have you did this?

Answer (score 2):

To override the template you just need to create **Magento_Ui** directory in your theme folder and place file in that folder.

like :

`app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Ui/web/templates/grid/listing.html`

now you can update / edit as you require.

Comment: I don't want to do with theme,can we do with module?I mean inside app/code/vendor/module?

Comment: you mean with custom module ?

Comment: Yes correct understood

Comment: did you try to override to map and override this file ? /vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/grid/listing.js and update " template: 'ui/grid/listing', to your desired template ?

Comment: nope,can you please write sample how to override that js? i don't know much about it.

Comment: did you find anything for me?